# How to pass value from VBA variable to R in RExcel macro

Tags: excel, vba, rexcel

I am new to writing RExcel macros, and I have a question. I am taking a user input from a macro through an `InputBox()`. The input is an integer. Then I want to pass this integer value to R.

This is my attempt:

```
Option Explicit
Sub KMeansClustering()
Dim k As Integer
RInterface.PutDataframe "mydata", Selection
RInterface.RRun "testdata <- na.omit(mydata)"
RInterface.RRun "testdata <- scale(testdata)"
k = InputBox("Enter k")    
' Supply data from VBA k variable to k R variable
RInterface.RRun "fit <- kmeans(testdata, k)"
RInterface.RRun "aggregate(testdata,by=list(fit$cluster),FUN=mean)"
RInterface.RRun "result <- data.frame(testdata, fit$cluster)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using "k" in R you must first transfer the value to an R variable (array):

Rinterface.PutArrayFromVBA("k_value", k)
Rinterface.RRun "fit <- kmeans(testdata, k_value)"